# Find parameter with regex

Tags: regex, sip

I have a SIP messsage.And I must take some parameter this SIP message.

SIP Message:

```
INVITE sip:103@192.168.1.33:5002 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.33:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-be6b8b6e6a23b03f-1---d8754z-;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:102@192.168.1.33:5060>
To: <sip:103@192.168.1.33:5060>
From: "102"<sip:102@192.168.1.33:5060>;tag=653bd245
Call-ID: NjY1NzU1YTZhZjIzMTYwM2MxMWY5YWNlZDM1MmEwZTg.
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REGISTER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, INFO, MESSAGE
Content-Type: application/sdp
Supported: replaces
User-Agent: 3CXPhoneSystem 10.0.23053.0
Content-Length: 855

v=0
o=3cxPS 257748369408 287175606273 IN IP4 192.168.1.33
s=3cxPS Audio call
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.33
t=0 0
m=audio 5007 RTP/AVP 8 0 101 98 9 3 100 97 103 15 4 104 105 106 107 18
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=rtpmap:98 iLBC/8000
a=fmtp:98 mode=30
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=fmtp:9 bitrate=64000
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:100 SPEEX/16000
a=rtpmap:97 SPEEX/8000
a=rtpmap:103 L16/8000
a=rtpmap:15 G728/8000
a=rtpmap:4 G723/8000
a=rtpmap:104 G726-16/8000
a=rtpmap:105 G726-24/8000
a=rtpmap:106 G726-32/8000
a=rtpmap:107 G726-40/8000
a=rtpmap:18 G729/8000
a=fmtp:18 annexb=no
a=sendrecv
m=video 5009 RTP/AVP 102 99 34
a=rtpmap:102 H263-1998/90000
a=fmtp:102 QCIF=1;CIF=1
a=rtpmap:99 H264/90000
a=fmtp:99 packetization-mode=1
a=rtpmap:34 H263/90000
a=fmtp:34 QCIF=1;CIF=1
a=sendrecv
```

İn message,
in 'From' parameter,'"102"' place by.

And
in 'Contact' parameter,'102@192.168.1.33' place by.

How can I do for this?

Comment: you probably have a sip stack to handle it(I mean, updating the caller name )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the regex:

```
From: +"(.+?)"
```

This would put 102 in capturing group 1.

```
Contact: +<sip:(.+)?:.+>
```

This would put '102@192.168.1.33' in capturing group 1.